# is "when will my day come" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Is *"when will my day come"* grammatically correct? If not, is there any alternatives for that kind of sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is perfectly fine.

[1] *When will my day come?*

is well attested in published literature, e.g. [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=3qs-AwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA158&dq=%22when%20will%20my%20day%20come%22&pg=PA158#v=onepage&q=%22when%20will%20my%20day%20come%22&f=false), [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=zs6KA8XMCBMC&lpg=PA68&dq=%22when%20will%20my%20day%20come%22&pg=PA68#v=onepage&q=%22when%20will%20my%20day%20come%22&f=false), [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=W7EPAAAAIAAJ&dq=%22when%20will%20my%20day%20come%22&pg=PA460#v=onepage&q=%22when%20will%20my%20day%20come%22&f=false), [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=haopPkSPlPAC&q=%22when+will+my+day+come%22&dq=%22when+will+my+day+come%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjf5dWGg_naAhWSMd8KHRXEBLYQ6AEIRTAL), ...

It is an interrogative sentence. Its 'canonical' counterpart is

[2] *My day will come* [an adjunct of time].

Here the adjunct of time may be any of *soon*, *tomorrow*, *next week*, *in five years*, etc.